# OP code for shifting operations, decoding a bitstream (Intel, ARM)

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, bit-manipulation

I am look for a bit stream improvement. Since I lost track of recent development within the op codes, I look for ways to improve the following operation:

```
Read 128 bit from stream
Consume x bits into another Variable
Consume x bits as long as bits are in the buffer
If buffer would underflow read some more 64bit.
```

This requires shifts and 'and' operations (masking) and xor / add.

I am interested in if a operation exists where I can push a number of bits from one 64bit / 32bit register to another register on individual scale (like pushing the register 5 bits to the left and the upper most 5 bits are pushed to the second register becoming the lowest 5 bits of it.

```
value <<= 5;
value += buffer >>> (64 - 5);
buffer <<= 5
```

What architecture (intel, AMD, ARM derivates) do provide a single operation for this?

Comment: no architeture supports such complex operation in a single instruction

Comment: Did you checked the chance of using MMX, SIMD or whatever for 128/256 bit registers and load those into two 64bit registers. Also using only those extended registers would be likely to be enough. So I guess your statement might be invalid.

Comment: For x86, the operation you describe can be achieved using `shld` and `shl`. PS: your C code is wrong. For correct code, the compiler is perfectly capable of generating the necessary instructions, especially if you have 128 bit integer support.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. ```SHLD``` i was looking for. Any idea about the performance penalty when compared to a simple shl? I do not use C code to create this I come from Java and generate direct assembler output.

Comment: even in SIMD there's no instruction for both adding and shifting 2 different registers at the same time. SHLD doesn't add the value either